# TabLayout with Tab selected counter

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout

What I would like to accomplish is:

When ever the user clicks on Tab 1, it should increment a counter and display it on the fragment. I originally thought about, using `tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener` how ever this did not work as it gave me the following error; `"setOnTabSelectedListener is deprecated`. I also tried doing `getId` however that did not work either as I was unable to register when the user clicked the tab.

Please help!

When ever the user clicks `Tanav Sharma` it should increment a counter that is displayed.

[image]

```
package tanav.sharma;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import tanav.sharma.R;
import tanav.sharma.OneFragment;
import tanav.sharma.TwoFragment;

import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TanavActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.ic_action_pro,
            R.drawable.ic_action_web
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tanav);

        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        /**
         * This button is responsible for taking the user back
         * to the main activity. Preventing the user from pressing
         * the back key multiple times.
         */
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();

    }

    private void setupTabIcons(){
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.tanav));
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }

    }


    /**
     * This function is responsible for prompting the user with a dialog box,
     * once the hit the back key on the app. Asking for confirmation if they,
     * really want to exit the app. If user selects Yes, the app will quit.
     * If the user selects cancel, the app will continue to run.
     */
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        CharSequence exit = getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.exit);
        CharSequence exit_message = getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.exit_message);

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(exit)
                .setMessage(exit_message)
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        TanavActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                    }
                }).create().show();
    }


}
```

Comment: Use `addOnTabSelectedListener()` instead of `setOnTabSelectedListener()`. Also, that's probably just a warning, not an error.

Comment: You might be able to add a regular `onClickListener` is all you want is counts...

Comment: @cricket_007 please look at updated code

Comment: @MikeM. please look at updated code

Comment: nvm guys, i figured it out

Comment: You can answer below with the solution  instead of the vague comment

Answer (score 0):

Below code works to keep count :)

```
package tanav.sharma;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import tanav.sharma.R;
import tanav.sharma.OneFragment;
import tanav.sharma.TwoFragment;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TanavActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private RatingBar ratingBar;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.ic_action_pro,
            R.drawable.ic_action_web
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tanav);

        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        /**
         * This button is responsible for taking the user back
         * to the main activity. Preventing the user from pressing
         * the back key multiple times.
         */
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

            int count_image = 0;
            int count_web = 0;
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                int position = tab.getPosition();
                if(position == 0){

                    count_image = count_image + 1;
                    TextView counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);
                    counter.setText(Integer.toString(count_image));

                }else if(position == 1){
                    //count_web = count_web + 1;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                count_image = count_image + 1;
                TextView counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);
                counter.setText(Integer.toString(count_image));
            }
        });
    }




    private void setupTabIcons(){
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.tanav));
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }

    }


    /**
     * This function is responsible for prompting the user with a dialog box,
     * once the hit the back key on the app. Asking for confirmation if they,
     * really want to exit the app. If user selects Yes, the app will quit.
     * If the user selects cancel, the app will continue to run.
     */
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        CharSequence exit = getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.exit);
        CharSequence exit_message = getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.exit_message);

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(exit)
                .setMessage(exit_message)
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        TanavActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                    }
                }).create().show();
    }


}
```